# accessing the user profile by clicking a link

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Good day! I am building an online learning site, wherein every user has their own account and they can view their profile through the link of "my profile" whenever they click it. I have tried connecting it to log in but it goes directly to the profile page. This is my codes for instructor_profile.php, how can I connect the link(my profile) from the instructor's menu to profile page? Thank you.

```
<?php  

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");    
 mysql_select_db("db_elearning");

 $idNumber = $_REQUEST['idNumber'];  

 $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_instructor WHERE idNumber = '$idNumber'");      
 $get2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get);  
 $username = $get2['username'];   
 $password = $get2['password'];   
 $lastName = $get2['lastName'];   
 $firstName = $get2['firstName'];    
 $middleName = $get2['middleName'];  
 $location = $get2['location'];    


?>  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><br />
</p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p align="center"><strong>Instructor's profile</strong> </p>
  <table border="0" width="30%" align="center">
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="username">Username</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="password">Password</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
    <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="lastName">Last name</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="firstName">First name</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="middleName">Middle name</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName" value="<?php echo $middleName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="location">Location</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php echo $location;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the instructor's log in, it just goes directly to the user's profile

```
<?php

$username  = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($username && $password){

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Connection to server failed!");
    mysql_select_db("db_elearning");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_instructor WHERE username ='$username'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($numrows != 0){

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $idNumber = $row['idNumber'];
            $dbname = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];

        }
        if($username==$dbname){
            if($password==$dbpassword){

                header("location:instructor_frame.html");

            if ($numrows ==1){
                header("location:instructor_profile.php?idNumber=$idNumber");
            }else{
                echo "Your password is incorrect!";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Your name is incorrect!";
        }

    }else{
        echo "This name is not registered!";    
    }

}else{
    echo "You have to type a name and password!";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Use GET instead of Request..

Comment: I'm confused it doesn't work

Comment: [accessing the user profile by clicking a link](http://www.sitepoint.com/users-php-sessions-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

i will tell you how i would do it:
first of all, i will create a config.php and functions.php, which i will include in index.php, 
here is my config.php:

```css
<?php
     $link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
     // Check connection
     if (!$link){
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
?>
```

here is my functions.php:

```css
<?php
     function getInstructorsProfileById($id){
          global $link;
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'tbl_instructor' WHERE 'idNumber' = '$idNumber'";
          $res = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
          $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
          return $row;
     }
?>
```

(Warning up in the code area i cant use the type of quotes i need, so be aware that on the table/column name, inside $sql, you have to use that type of quotes, on my keyboard is on the left of the key 1 it also has ~ if shift is pressed)
and my index.php page is:

```css
<?php
    include 'config.php';//necesarily the first
    include 'function.php'; // so it would have the global $link variable to call
    if(isset($_GET['idNumber'])){ 
        $someVar = getInstructorsProfileById($_GET['idNumber']);
        extract($someVar);
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p align="center"><strong>Instructor's profile</strong> </p>
  <table border="0" width="30%" align="center">
    <tr><td width="40%">
      <label for="username">Username</label> </td> <td>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>" />
    </td> </tr>
    <tr><td width="40%">
      <label for="password">Password</label> </td> <td>
      <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password;?>" />
    </td> </tr>
    <tr><td width="40%">
      <label for="lastName">Last name</label> </td> <td>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<?php echo $lastName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="firstName">First name</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<?php echo $firstName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="middleName">Middle name</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName" value="<?php echo $middleName;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  </td> </tr>
  <tr><td width="40%">
    <label for="location">Location</label> </td> <td>
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="<?php echo $location;?>" />
  </td> </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php }else{
          echo "some error if there is no number assigned";
     }
?>
```

and the link to this page would be:
`<?php $idNumber =7; // the number you know you need, example 7 ?>`
`<a href="localhost/index.php?idNumber=<?php echo $idNumber; ?>">My Profile</a>`

but this is not the best way, to have a better approach try and search the web for the words session_start(), $_SESSION in php syntax
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you  but I'm encountering this problem:
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3